# CDI bean extends from a generic class

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I want a DAO that extends from a generic DAO like this:

```
public abstract class DAO<T> implements Serializable{

private Class<T> entityClass;

public DAO(){

}

public void setClass(Class<T> entityClass){
    this.entityClass=entityClass;
} 

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
```

and the CDI bean that extends from the generic class and is injected in an EJB

```
@Named("daoImpl")
@RequestScoped
public class DAOImpl extends DAO implements Serializable{


@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pruebaEJBPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}


public DAOImpl() {

    setClass(User.class);
}
```

I have to use the setClass method because I want to inject this bean in an EJB and it can´t have an arg-constructor.

This way works but it throws a warning that i can't avoid: WARNING:   The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class from public void p1.dao.setClase(java.lang.Class) is not resolvable to a concrete type.

Is there another way to extend a CDI bean from a generic class or avoid the warnings? If i use an EJB like Netbeans does, all is fine but i don't want to use an EJB for a DAO. If i don't use a CDI bean, how can i inject a simple DAO in an EJB?

Comment: What IDE is giving you this warning? I don't get it in NB 8.0

Comment: NB 8.0 with Glassfish 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this warning comes up since your generic DAO is parameterized but your concrete implementation of the DAO doesn't specify a parameter type. Add the type to your DAOImpl class declaration an you should be fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It throws a EJBException causes by a Dao method.

Comment: Please attach the stack trace. Which method throws the exception?

Comment: When DAOImpl class definition is: public class daoImpl<User> extends dao implements Serializable{ then it doesn't compile and the error is "cannot select from a type variable". If the class definition is: public class daoImpl extends dao<User> implements Serializable{ then compiles but it doesn´t work. A simple "service.findAll() doesn't retrive anithing.

Comment: But what do you mean by service.findAll()? Shall that be a method of your abstract DAO to find all entities of the respective type?

Comment: Sure, the correct way is UserDao.findAll(). I found that the problem was that netbeans was deploying the old version because i tried these changes one thousand times. Thanks.